# how do I locate the error In my syntax for sql insert statement?

Tags: java, mysql

I cannot find the problem in the syntax for my insert into statement. I am trying to insert it into certain columns. I have a feeling that it has to do with the quotes, but I am not sure.

```
    @Override
public void addToDatabase() {
    try {
        // 1. get a connection to database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/Bank", "kculbreth36",
                "Gerder11");
        // 2. create a statement
        Statement st = myConn.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO budgeting (Food, Entertainment, Clothes, Utilities, Total Spendings)"
                + " VALUES (food, entertainment, clothes, utilities, totalValue)");
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert SQL syntax is wrong, you can have column name with space `Total Spendings`. Also `VALUES` should be in single quote for constant sql string. Learn SQL syntax https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

Having SQL like

```
VALUES (food, entertainment, clothes, utilities, totalValue)
```

is making sql think that `food` etc are columns names not variables.

You are better off using a `PrepaparedStatement` like

```
"INSERT INTO budgeting (Food, Entertainment, Clothes, Utilities, Total Spendings)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

and then using the `set` methods

```
st.setString (1, food);  // assuming that food is a variable
```

or

```
st.setString(1, "Hotdog"); // for a hard-coded value
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

**edit** also note the comment made by @MohamedSaligh

Comment: What exactly would be put into those question marks? Or are they just place holders and the 1 for the set string is the order of which its called out like an array index.

Comment: Yes they are placeholders - see the link I gave you, there are more examples.

Comment: i have done that, now it lists an error that they are undefined for the type statement.